# A quicker way to approach the indefinite integral $\int{\frac{x^3dx}{1+x^5}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Problem:   Evaluate the integral $$\int{\frac{x^3dx}{1+x^5}}$$

Source: Given to me as a challenge. I can't seem to find a valid substitution for the integral. Also the way should be quick enough to apply in a timed test. I don't know the answer and I have almost given up. I called the challenger and he said that I can ask for help but not look up on Wolfram or any such website as it won't be a proper solution. I don't think it is solvable though :p

My try: Well, I have tried to get around by using many substitutions which make the thing more complicated than it already is. Also I'm looking for the QUICKEST way to approach this problem in case  it happens to meet me on a test.

Comment: Are you able to integrate functions of the form $\frac{1}{\alpha-x}$? Well, then apply a partial fraction decomposition. The integrand function is a meromorphic function with simple poles at $-1$ and at the primitive tenth roots of unity.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm quite sorry to say that I didn't get a single thing you said..after all I'm a high school student!

Comment: The answer to this is an absolute nightmare. I'm not sure I could even figure out how to get the closed form solution.

Comment: @YourAverageEuler: in such a case, don't care about it. Something like that will not appear on your test.

Comment: Hope I could look it up...I think it would be a bunch of logarithms and inverse trig functions maybe $arcsin$

Comment: @YourAverageEuler: logarithms and arctangents, given by the primitives of $\frac{1}{x+1}$ or $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ and similar objects. *Why* has been explained.

Comment: So should I just give up, gosh I would've won that cash! But for the love of math, we'll figure it out.

Comment: Every rational function is integrable.

Comment: You will get a solution using partial fractions: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%C2%B3%2F(1%2Bx%E2%81%B5)+partial+fraction , but these things become messy to integrate, the first 2 terms will have an arctan primitive and the last term will have a logarithmic primitive. I don't think this is something to expect on a test, but as an exercise it might be worth it.

Comment: Partial fraction ... not sure this will be best ? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions((x%5E3)%2F(1%2Bx%5E5))

Comment: it's too much to calculate, isn't it? Another approach other than partials? Anyone?

Comment: there is no other Approach since the Integrand is a rational function

Comment: $$\int \frac{x^3}{1+x^5}dx=\int\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^5}+1}dx$$ Now let $\frac 1x=t$. To covert it to $$-\int \frac{1}{t^5+1}$$This is the first thought came to me, I too don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: and we get a rational function again

Comment: So can we render this unsolvable for the average mathematician? I'll keep the post open for suggestions.

Comment: should i post the answer for you?

Comment: @YourAverageEuler Not too fast. At least wait for a day, even then if there isn't any simple answer, then come to this conclusion.

Comment: Nah I just phoned the guy and said I'm out...I already looked up the answer now and I was happy to see it...That guy just wasted 2 days of my life for this inhumane problem!

Comment: @YourAverageEuler lol it dosent deserve even an hour of yout life

Comment: @YourAverageEuler  seems like you are a Indian JEE aspirant

Comment: Cf. the similar integral here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135455/evaluating-indefinite-integrals-of-the-form-int-fracx2-dxa-x5-b

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $1+x^5$ factors as 
$$(1+x)(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4) = (1+x)(1 + ax + x^2)(1 + bx + x^2)$$
for appropriate $a, b$.  Then use partial fractions.

And this is NOT an appropriate question for a timed test.

Comment: With $a=-\phi$ and $b=\phi-1=\dfrac{1}{\phi}$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Definitely not appropriate for a timed test. One can eliminate the $x^3$ in the numerator by the substitution $x=u^{-1}$.

Comment: Will use the approach when I'll have time. Thanks! And yeah it's tedious and boring actually, just mind bending calculations

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align}
K(a)&= \int \frac{1-a t}{t^2-2a t+1}dx\\
&=-\frac a2 \ln(t^2-2a t+1)+\sqrt{1-a^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{t-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}
\end{align}
$$\frac5{t^5+1}=\frac1{t+1}+\frac{2(1-t\cos\frac\pi5)}{t^2-2 t\cos\frac\pi5+1}+ \frac{2(1-t\cos\frac{3\pi}5)}{t^2-2t \cos\frac{3\pi}5 +1}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\int \frac1{t^5+1}dt&= \frac15\ln(t+1) +\frac25K(\cos\frac \pi5) +\frac25K(\cos\frac {3\pi}5 )
\end{align}
Then, with $x=\frac1t$
$$\int \frac{x^3}{x^5+1}dx= -\int \frac1{t^5+1}dt
$$